# Do the name of component in Reactjs have to be the same with file containing definition of the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, naming-conventions

I'm starting learning about reactjs. But when i watch tutorial on youtube i often see that when definite component in sperate file and export, people always name the file name with component name defining in the file is similar.
For example:I see that to define a component name **Book** the video always names the file of Book component is** Book.js**
And i wonder that this is official rule of reactjs or may be convention of Reactjs community.

Can i name the file name and component in the file is difference?

Comment: You don't have to do that. It's just make it easier to navigate the project

Comment: @Konrad i have not understood clearly yet. For example, i want to create a component name Book and can i name file which export the Book component is peter.js or john.js?

Comment: Yes, you can do this

Comment: @Konrad It's very kind of you. thank you very much

Comment: A component is just a function in the end. You can name a file Dog.js and have a component inside called cat. The important thing is to be as clear as possible to keep an easy to understand structure

Comment: Make sure your component name is `capitalised`, since that is the rule to treat it as a react component. This may be out of context, but I felt like sharing :-). [refer here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't care about your filenames at all (and in fact, if you use a bundler, it's going to combine source files into a small number of scripts for distribution). You can put one component in each file, or all of your components in a single file, and either way, it makes no difference to React. Components are just functions (either function components using hooks, or constructor functions for `class` components). Organize them as you see fit.

Here's an example with three components in the same script tag (loosely, "file"):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Ticker = ({start}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(start);

    useEffect(() => {
        setValue(start);
    }, [start]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setValue((v) => v + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, []);
    
    return <span className="counter">{value}</span>;
};

const Strong = ({children}) => <strong>{children}</strong>;

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Strong>Testing: <Ticker start={1} /></Strong>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: <subjective>Putting *every single component* in its own file is probably overkill. It's useful for tutorials because they are usually dealing with just a couple of components, but in a real page/application, you'll have **lots** of components. Group them by relatedness and functionality. From one of the React lead developers: *"If you strictly follow the rule of one component per file, you’re not taking advantage of JS flexibility. One function per file is overly rigid — why apply the same to components? ...*

Comment: *... It’s helpful to break implementation details apart without exporting. (If your library allows that.)"* ([twitter link](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1439304400464449536))</subjective>

Answer (score -1):

These rules are generally accepted by developers. Even the eslint rules will show an error. But the react will work with other names as well